# Why does boost::ptr_list uses underlying void *?

Tags: c++, boost

The boost [ptr_list documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html) states that the container uses an underlying `std::list<void*>`.

Why are they using this type instead of a more specialized `std::list<T*>`?

Comment: Its tough to say as i dont have idea about boost . But the connection i can see is void * can be typecasted to any type so it makes it might make it similar to  T* as you are talking about . Any ways would be waiting eagerly for answers from other respected members of our society

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably to cut down on the number of template instantiations. If it uses a `std::list<T*>`, then every use of `ptr_list<T>` would also instantiate `std::list<T*>`. That's a lot of instantiations if you use `ptr_list` a lot.

Comment: Makes sense. Seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 3):

This makes it easy to share almost all the code regardless of the type(s) over which you instantiate it. Nearly all the code is in the single `std::list<void *>`. Each instantiation only adds code to cast between `T *` and `void *` where needed.

Of course, modern compilers/linkers can do a fair amount of this without such help, but that hasn't always been the case (and some people still use older tool chains, for various reasons).

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean : boost::ptr_list and std::list are templates, so they should works whatever underlying type it is, isn't it ? Why would it be required to use void* ?